# How to insert values in a table in Azure Synapse Analytics?

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse-analytics

I am trying to create a table in Azure Synapse Analytics with the following script and the table gets created.

```
CREATE TABLE [PS].[BCGrps](
    [OC] varchar (80) NOT NULL,
    [BID] int NOT NULL,
    [Active] BIT NOT NULL,
    [UniAccess]  BIT NOT NULL,
    [Indus]  BIT NOT NULL
)
```

however when I try to insert values in this:

```
INSERT INTO [PS].[BCGrps](OC,BID,Active,UniAccess,Indus)
VALUES 
('xx',200,1,1,1), 
('xxx',202,1,0,1), 
('xxxxx',2000,1,0,1), 
('yy',2030,1,0,0), 
('zz',2002,0,0,1)
```

I get the error:

> Parse error at line: 3, column: 22: Incorrect syntax near ','.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This behaviour is in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql): *"Table value constructor is not supported in Azure Synapse Analytics. Instead, subsequent `INSERT` statements can be executed to insert multiple rows. In Azure Synapse Analytics, insert values can only be constant literal values or variable references. To insert a non-literal, set a variable to non-constant value and insert the variable."*

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [PS].[BCGrps]
SELECT 'xx',200,1,1,1
UNION ALL SELECT 'xxx',202,1,0,1 
UNION ALL SELECT 'xxxxx',2000,1,0,1 
UNION ALL SELECT 'yy',2030,1,0,0
UNION ALL SELECT 'zz',2002,0,0,1
```